# Why did Google abandon GData?

Tags: api, google-api, odata, gdata, google-data-api

Looking at the [Google Data APIs home page](https://developers.google.com/gdata/) (GData), it lists that:

> Most newer Google APIs are not Google Data APIs. The Google Data APIs
>   documentation applies only to the older APIs that are listed in the Google Data APIs directory.

The [Google Data APIs Blog](http://googledataapis.blogspot.com/) is now offline so I can't get any answers from there.

Has there ever been any reason given to explain why Google has apparently chosen to abandon GData in favour of system specific APIs?

Microsoft, IBM and others are still pushing [OData](http://www.odata.org/) which is a similar (but more mature) concept, why don't they arrive at the same reasons?

The only reasonable reason that I can think of, is to better facilitate for globally distributed scalability and caching. Or perhaps there were performance and index related complications with having the data user-queryable.

Answer (score 1):

> For information about a specific new API, see that API's
>   documentation. For information about authorizing requests with a newer
>   API, see Google Accounts Authentication and Authorization.

Your Google API start page should be [this one](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/) now.
I think that you should read [this post](http://greatdanephotos.com/geek/2012/03/do-not-use-gdata-java-api/), about Calendar Data API vs. Google Calendar API Client.

Short story: new API is more consistent and uses OAuth 2.0.